# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object kotlin.Lazy.getValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin

Sorry for my stupid question.

I have Google this problem, but the answer couldn't work for me.

This is my code.

```
  data class Article(val id: Long, val title: String, val ingress: String, val image: String,
                       val dateTime: String, val tags: List<String>, val content: List<Item>, val created: Long, val changed: Long) {

        @delegate:Transient
        val formatDateString: String by lazy {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm")
            val date: Date = sdf.parse(dateTime)
            var time: String?
            if (date.year == Date().year) {
                time = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM,HH:mm", Locale.US).format(date)
            } else {
                time = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy,HH:mm", Locale.US).format(date)
            }
            time!!
        }

    }
```

when i try to get `formatDateString` value , Above exception will happen.

The codes access `formatDateString` as following

```
  override fun getCustomAdapter(): BaseQuickAdapter<CarListResponseBody.Article, BaseViewHolder> {
        return object : BaseQuickAdapter<CarListResponseBody.Article, BaseViewHolder>( R.layout.app_item_cars_list,dataList) {
            override fun convert(helper: BaseViewHolder, item: CarListResponseBody.Article) {
                helper.setText(R.id.tv_ingress,item.ingress)
                helper.setText(R.id.tv_date_time,item.formatDateString)
                helper.setText(R.id.tv_title,item.title)
                ImageLoadUtil.loadImgToView(context,item.image,helper.getView(R.id.img_car),null)
            }
        }
    }
```

I think this exception caused by Gson, But i have no idea why

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not a pro but I'd like to tell you what I've found. Let's create a simple class to see how delegates in Kotlin work. Just in case, I'm using Kotlin `1.3.70`. Here is our simple class:

```kotlin
class Test {
    val test by lazy { "test" }
}
```

In the Idea or Android Studio, you can check the bytecode. But it's pretty hard to read JVM bytecode at least for me :) Let's convert it to something looks like Java:

```java
...
public final class Test {
   @NotNull
   private final Lazy test$delegate;

   @NotNull
   public final String getTest() {
      Lazy var1 = this.test$delegate;
      Object var3 = null;
      boolean var4 = false;
      return (String)var1.getValue();
   }

   public Test() {
      this.test$delegate = LazyKt.lazy((Function0)null.INSTANCE);
   }
}
...
```

As you see Kotlin creates a special field for `lazy` delegate which initializes in the constructor. The problem is Gson uses [UnsafeAllocator](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/ConstructorConstructor.java#L94) and doesn't call the constructor. You can read a bit more about it for example [here](https://medium.com/@programmerr47/gson-unsafe-problem-d1ff29d4696f). So when you deserialize your `Article` object it contains `null` instead of appropriate `lazy` delegate. That's why you got a null pointer exception when trying to call this del

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any ideas to sort this problem out? Or better solution for ```formatDateString```

Comment: As a quick solution, you can write an extension function. But it will cause some overhead if you are going to call `formatDateString` frequently. Also, you can use wrapper with `formatDateString` in it. But it won't be very convenient to use. maybe you can consider migrating from Gson to Moshi or kotlinx.serialization but it's a pretty big amount of work

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem when using properties not filled by `Gson`. I used the following work around

```
var myString: String? = null
    get() {
        if (field == null) {
            field = "myInitialValue"
        }
        return field
    }
```

which I guess would be this then in your example:

```
val formatDateString: String? = null
    get() {
        if (field == null) {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm")
            val date: Date = sdf.parse(dateTime)
            var time: String?
            if (date.year == Date().year) {
                time = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM,HH:mm", Locale.US).format(date)
            } else {
                time = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy,HH:mm", Locale.US).format(date)
            }
            field = time!!
        }
        return field
    }
```

I have no idea if it's bad practice but it seems to do the job for me

Answer (score 0):

I also have had the exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object kotlin.Lazy.getValue()' on a null object reference" when tried to write a method inside a data class (for Gson).

```
data class SomeResponse(
    override val success: Int,
    override val errors: ErrorsResponse?
) {

    data class ErrorsResponse(
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int?
    ) {

        private val errorUtil by lazy { ErrorUtil() }

        fun getErrorMessage(): String? =
            errorUtil.getErrorMessage(id)
    }
}
```

No matter, `errorUtil by lazy { ErrorUtil() }` or `errorUtil = ErrorUtil()`, it will be `null` when we call `getErrorMessage`. It won't be initialized so soon.

To overcome this, initialize the variable when calling.

```
private var errorUtil: ErrorUtil? = null

fun getErrorMessage(): String? {
    if (errorUtil == null) errorUtil = ErrorUtil()
    return errorUtil!!.getErrorMessage(id)
}
```